# Manipulating array in vue3 using v-model [edited]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

The question has three parts revolving around two files App.vue and X Array.vue :-

1.When value of input is changed, how it could be written back to the array?

2.If the value entered is empty how to remove the element from array?

3.How to show one extra input element always so that it is possible to add new values(linked with 2)?

XArray should basically be an array editor.

App.vue

```html
    <template>
       <div>
        <XArray v-model="myArray" />
        <pre>{{ myArray }}</pre>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
     import XArray from './components/XArray.vue';

     export default {

     components: {
       XArray,
      },

     data: () => {
     return {
      myArray: ['one', 'two'],
            };
       },
     };
     </script>
```

XArray.vue

```html
    <template>
      <input
       v-for="(option, index) in modelValue"
       :key="index"
       @input="$emit('update:modelValue', [...modelValue, `${$event.target.value}`])" 
       />
    </template>

    <script>
     export default {
     props: {
       modelValue: {
         type: Array,
         required: true,
       },
     };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      myArray: ['one', 'two'],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addEl() {
      this.myArray.push('new')
    }
  }
})

app.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <input
       v-for="(option, index) in modelValue"
       :key="index"
       @input="$emit('update:modelValue', upd(index, $event.target.value))" 
       :value="option"
     />
   </div>
  `,
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    upd(idx, val) {
      return val ? [
        ...this.modelValue.map((item, i) =>
          i !== idx
            ? item
            : val
        ),
      ] : this.modelValue.length > 1 ? 
            [ ...this.modelValue.filter((item, i) => {
              if(i !== idx) return item
            })] : 
            [ "last" ]
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child v-model="myArray"></child>
  <pre>{{ myArray }}</pre>
  <button @click="addEl">add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hello @nikolaPavicevic your solution worked fine. I edited the question a bit, can u help me out with the 3rd part of the current question?

Comment: @Anubhav Negi hey mate, try now I updated my answer just prevent deletion of the last array element , cheers :)